# TDengine Want to Use Multiple Path for Storing Data

Tags: database, iot

I am thinking about using different path when storing databases, and noticed the following config in TDengine's config file.

```
# data file's directory
# dataDir                   /var/lib/taos
```

Is it possible to set multiple dataDir and letting TDengine store files in several paths?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, TDengine support multi-tier storage system, which you can store in different path(files) and set different tiers. However, it only support in the TDengine Enterprise Edition, which is a paid version.

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much for the your information. I will check the supported features of TDengine Enterprise Edition.